# QToolbar how does the Extension button get called?

Tags: c++, qt

to start off with:
I'm using QT Creator 5.4.1 for C++.

I need to override the function/ feature on the QToolbar widget called Extension, or the Extension button. I've read through the QT Docs and there doesnt seem to be a function which I can call/ override to change the functionality of this, normally when there are too many actions on the QToolbar the Extension button appears and allows me to click and dropdown to another/ extended toolbar. Does anyone know what calls it? Or what the function/Method actually is?

In the QT Doc's it says this

"When a toolbar is resized in such a way that it is too small to show all the items it contains, an extension button will appear as the last item in the toolbar. Pressing the extension button will pop up a menu containing the items that does not currently fit in the toolbar."

But no references or hyper-links to any function calls, or anything that it relates too.
Thanks

Comment: This looks related to or even is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482416/qtoolbar-force-expand-on-too-many-qactions).

Comment: No one is asking what signals get fired and how, and the other question is how to force expand the QToolbar. Different questions.

Answer (score 3):

This question is pretty old, but in-case anyone else runs into it...

The extension toolbar gets shown with QToolBarLayout::setExpanded(). It is called via QToolBarLayout which connects with the extension (QToolBarExtension) button's clicked signal in QToolBarLayout::setUsePopupMenu.