# QToolbar force expand on too many QActions

Tags: c++, qt

Hi all is there any way to automatically expand a QToolbar if there is too many QActions in?

Using Qt version 5.4.1 C++11

Ive tried :`ui->mainToolBar->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred)`

But this only expands it horizontally. I need it to expand vertically like the Expand button does.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. What happens at the moment if you add many QActions? Do you get an expand button? What do you mean by expanding vertically like the expand button does? Do you want a tool bar to expand vertically (like a grid of icons)? I think no tool bar does that, and it's probably not supported by Qt. Maybe also include the code needed for us to quickly try it out.

Comment: When a toolbar is resized in such a way that it is too small to show all the items it contains, an extension button will appear as the last item in the toolbar. Pressing the extension button will pop up a menu containing the items that does not currently fit in the toolbar. From the Qt Documentation. But I need a way to force this to happen and not on  the extension button click.

Answer (score 1):

Always expanding a toolbar vertically is not possible as far as I know (never seen it). A solution would be to add multiple toolbars. This way, you can arrange them one under the other.

What you can try is to add a custom widget to the toolbar that grows horizontally. This was proposed [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52100-Horizontally-Scrolling-QToolbar) by using a QScrollArea... Not sure whether this is exactly what you want, but it may work good enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can make a function to expand/retract a QToolbar. Firstly using a Forloop get all the child widgets from the QToolbar. You can use a Bool to lock to only get the first Widget which is the Expanding button/Action.

```
bool get_first_action{true};
for(QWidget* widget : ui->myToolBar->findChildren<QWidget*>())
{
    if(get_first_action)
    {

        get_first_action = false;
        // This is the expanding action!
        m_action_expand = widget;
    }
}
```

Or you can do this which is probably a bit safer.

```
for(QWidget* widget : ui->myToolBar->findChildren<QWidget*>())
{
    if(widget->objectName() == "qt_toolbar_ext_button")
    {
        // This is the expanding action!
        m_action_expand = widget;
    }
}
```

Once you have the sneaky expanding action assign it to a member varible

```
// Make sure to initialize this in the constructor!
// m_action_expand = new QWidget(this // parent)
QWidget* m_action_expand;
```

Now create a handy function with a good name;

```
void MainWindow::forceToolbarExpand()
{
    // Grab the position of the expanding action/widget
    QPointF pos(m_action_expand->pos());

    // Create a fake/dummy event that replicates the mouse button press
    QMouseEvent event_press(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton,0, 0);

    // Create a fake/dummy event that replicates the mouse button release
    QMouseEvent event_release(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pos, Qt::LeftButton,0, 0);

    // These two events together will fire the QAction::Toggled signal.

    // Make sure to send the events!
    QApplication::sendEvent(m_action_expand, &event_press);
    QApplication::sendEvent(m_action_expand, &event_release);
}
```

And there we have it your QToolbar, if it can be expanded/retracted now will when you call this function. I'm not too sure if you can directly Moc/fake the toggled event but you can try it. I know this method works so yeah.

Comment: A side note: `bool get_first_action{true};` is C++11. You should mention that so that people don't look at it bewildered or even better - use the classic notation `bool get_first_action = true;`. No need to add new fancy-pancy syntax if the OP hasn't specifically asked for C++11.

Comment: I am the original poster :P. I should of mentioned what version of C++ i was using and what version of Qt. Ill update the question to make it more relevant.

Comment: Ah, dang it. Sorry, didn't look at the name. :D

Comment: Aha thats cool! Man its taken me all day to work out how to do this. Qt doc's show nothing on the Expanding Actions stuff. Might send a request to the Qt dev team to add some more explanation into how the Expanding button works and ways you can invoke expanding and retracting via code.

Comment: Sending them request for writing documentation? Good luck on that... LOL Btw if you know PyQt or PySide...Or let me put it this way: if you know Python I suggest you do some combo search in the future using the documentation of the three combined. Sometimes you might get lucky and find something (even examples) that is not present in the documentation of the rest. I hit a couple of times the jackpot since I started also working with PyQt. :))) Then you can simply port the code (or see how you can improve your search queries) for the C++ API.